# Getting cumulative counts of word frequencies founds in a documents

Tags: python, nltk, word-frequency, trend

I have been trying to detect word/bigram trends over pieces of text. What I have done so far is removing stop words, lowercasing and getting word frequencies and appended the top common 30 per text to a list,

e.g.

```
[(u'seeing', 2), (u'said.', 2), (u'one', 2), (u'death', 2), (u'entertainment',   2), (u'it\u2019s', 2), (u'weiss', 2), (u'read', 2), (u'\u201cit', 1), (u'shot', 1), (u'show\u2019s', 1), (u'people', 1), (u'dead,\u201d', 1), (u'bloody', 1),...]
```

Then I converted the lists above to one huge list containing all words and their per doc frequencies and what I need to do now is get back a sorted list, i.e.:

```
[(u'snow', 32), (u'said.', 12), (u'GoT', 10), (u'death', 8), (u'entertainment', 4)..]
```

Any ideas?

Code:

```
fdists = []
for i in texts:
    words = FreqDist(w.lower() for w in i.split() if w.lower() not in    stopwords)
    fdists.append(words.most_common(30))

all_in_one = [item for sublist in fdists for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Why would you not use a dictionary?

Comment: From the start in order to capture every unique word's occurrence or after the for loop?

Comment: I tried using collection.Counter from the start but it takes forever to execute..

Comment: Instead of using a list to store words use a dictionary and then sort based on the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want to do is sort your list you can use

```
import operator

fdists = [(u'seeing', 2), (u'said.', 2), (u'one', 2), (u'death', 2), (u'entertainment',   2), (u'it\u2019s', 2), (u'weiss', 2), (u'read', 2), (u'\u201cit', 1), (u'shot', 1), (u'show\u2019s', 1), (u'people', 1), (u'dead,\u201d', 1), (u'bloody', 1)]
fdists2 = [(u'seeing', 3), (u'said.', 4), (u'one', 2), (u'death', 2), (u'entertainment',   2), (u'it\u2019s', 2), (u'weiss', 2), (u'read', 2)]
fdists += fdists2

fdict = {}
for i in fdists:
    if i[0] in fdict:
        fdict[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
        fdict[i[0]] = i[1]

sorted_f = sorted(fdict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print sorted_f[:30]

[(u'said.', 6), (u'seeing', 5), (u'death', 4), (u'entertainment', 4), (u'read', 4), (u'it\u2019s', 4), (u'weiss', 4), (u'one', 4), (u'\u201cit', 1), (u'shot', 1), (u'show\u2019s', 1), (u'people', 1), (u'dead,\u201d', 1), (u'bloody', 1)]
```

Another way you can handle duplicates is to use pandas `groupby()` function and then use the `sort()` function to sort by `count` and `word` like so

```
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd

fdists = [(u'seeing', 2), (u'said.', 2), (u'one', 2), (u'death', 2), (u'entertainment',   2), (u'it\u2019s', 2), (u'weiss', 2), (u'read', 2), (u'\u201cit', 1), (u'shot', 1), (u'show\u2019s', 1), (u'people', 1), (u'dead,\u201d', 1), (u'bloody', 1)]
fdists2 = [(u'seeing', 3), (u'said.', 4), (u'one', 2), (u'death', 2), (u'entertainment',   2), (u'it\u2019s', 2), (u'weiss', 2), (u'read', 2)]
fdists += fdists2

df = DataFrame(data = fdists, columns = ['word','count'])
df= DataFrame([{'word': k, 'count': (v['count'].sum())} for k,v in df.groupby(['word'])], columns = ['word','count'])

Sorted = df.sort(['count','word'], ascending = [0,1])
print Sorted[:30]

             word  count
8           said.      6
9          seeing      5
2           death      4
3   entertainment      4
4            it’s      4
5             one      4
7            read      4
12          weiss      4
0          bloody      1
1          dead,”      1
6          people      1
10           shot      1
11         show’s      1
13            “it      1
```

Comment: Is this way gonna find cumulative counts of words? By this I mean that if the word death is mentioned in two documents, 5 times and 2 times respectively, at the end the word count of the word "death" will be 7 or there will be 2 separate entries? Thank you

Comment: @Swan87 I updated the pandas answer to account for duplicates

Comment: @Swan87 both answers updated but I prefer the pandas one personally. I think it looks cleaner and you could manipulate your dataframe a lot easier than a list if you want to do other things with it.